# Issue while downloading a large playlist ( 200+ videos) using YouTube -dl

Tags: youtube-dl

```
[youtube] h6863vjJ9Ds: Downloading webpage ERROR: unable to download
video data: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

I am facing this issue while downloading and extracting audio from a music playlist of 250+ videos.
I start the process and it continues for 20+ videos but then it stops.
And display the message above.
I tried removing Cache but it didn't help.

Comment: Maybe concurrency rate limiting?

Comment: I don't know what that is @danh

Comment: Public apis place limits on usage so that they won't be attacked or taken advantage of. One sort limits how many requests a client can have going concurrently.  Something about it ought to be in youtube docs.

Answer (score 0):

Try it again but add the flag after the command:

```
youtube-dl --ignore-errors
```

In my experience, if a playlist has an entry that is restricted by age or location or has been deleted, then it will bork and stop right away. The above will skip the entry that is causing difficulties and continue.

Note, though, that when downloading playlists, due to the response youtube-dl gets from YouTube, it is limited to download the first 100 entries in a playlist, annoyingly.

youtube-dl is hosted on GitHub, and given the enormous number of pending pull requests (900+) and reported issues (3.9k), I don't think anyone is actively putting much work into maintaining it anymore.